# Grails NumberFormatException

Tags: grails, groovy, cron

I am receiving `NumberFormatException` error in my `Grails` code which is to sort movies into a database. The error suggests it is from the `cron` plugin. I have done my research and I have been trying to catch the error by using `NumberFormatException` but to no avail. I think the problem lies in the `IndexService`. Any help would be much appreciated.

The exact error is:

```
2014-07-25 10:09:07,779 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
Message: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"
```

I am using:

```
Grails version: 2.4.2
Groovy version: 2.3.3
JVM version: 1.7.0_51
quartz - 1.0.2
```

**My code:**

IndexService

```
package movie

import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class IndexService {

    static transactional = false

    def grailsApplication
    private cleanText(String title)
    {
        //split string into array via .,+,[,] etc...
        def splitTitle=(title.toLowerCase()).tokenize('+.[]!£$%^+=~#:; \t \n \r \f / \\ { } @ & - ( )')
        //Get rid of extention
        splitTitle.remove(splitTitle.size()-1)

        //Get rid of Dvdrip and author
        //unwanted phrases
        def unwanted=["dvdrip","eng","www","torentz","3xforum","bugz","ro","maxspeed","xvid","720p","bluray","yify","1080p","hd","x264","RARBG","mp3","mp4","flv","brrip","rip"]
        //Get rid of dates
        //get 2000 to current date to put into the unwanted list
        for(i in 2000..3000){unwanted.add(i.toString())}
        //def empty string to put all our cleaned up text into
        def cleanedText = ""
        //cleaning up word mess...
        splitTitle.each {word->
            if(!unwanted.contains(word))
            {
                cleanedText=cleanedText+word+" "
            }
        }
        //returning with +'s
        return (cleanedText[0..-2]).replaceAll("\\s","+")
    }

    def getInfo(String title)
    {
        //returned nice with +
        def cleanTitle=cleanText(title)
        //define my reader
        def scan = new JsonSlurper()
        def scanner =scan.parseText(("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&plot=full&t="+cleanTitle).toURL().text)
        if(scanner.Response=="True")
        {
            /*
            organisied like this:
            String artwork
            String title
            Date dateReleased
            String userRated
            String lengthOfFilm
            String genre
            String plot
            float rating
 */         //returns our info we have scraped
            return [
                    true,
                    scanner.Poster,
                    scanner.Title,
                    new Date(scanner.Released),
                    scanner.Rated,
                    scanner.Runtime,
                    scanner.Genre,
                    scanner.Plot,
                    scanner.imdbRating.toFloat()/10
            ]
        }
        else
        {
            return [null,cleanTitle]
        }


    }
    def indexFiles()
    {
        //returns fileLocation
        def fileLocation=grailsApplication.config.grails.movie.location
        //Setup as file object
        def dir = new File(fileLocation)
        //recurse all files
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->

            println(file)
            //only create a record if no file test if record exists
            if(!Record.findByPathToFile(file.getCanonicalPath())) {
                //get record propreties set
                def record = new Record()
                record.pathToFile = file.getCanonicalPath()
                //call to get data of a film returns as a list
                def info = getInfo(file.getName())
                //check if everthing is alright
                info.each{print(it)}
                if (info[0] == null) {
                    try {
                        //set fallback propeties
                        record.artwork = null
                        record.title = info[1].replaceAll("\\+"," ")
                        record.genre = null
                        record.dateReleased = new Date(file.lastModified())
                        record.lengthOfFilm = null
                        record.plot = null
                        record.rating = 0
                        record.userRated = null
                        record.save(failOnError: true)
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        //catch any errors
                        log.error("Error caught :${e} \n")
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //set good propeties
                        record.artwork = info[1]
                        record.title = info[2]
                        record.genre = info[6]
                        record.dateReleased = info[3]
                        record.lengthOfFilm = info[5]
                        record.plot = info[7]
                        print(info[8])
                        record.rating = info[8]
                        record.userRated = info[4]
                        record.save(failOnError: true)
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        //catch any errors
                        info.each
                                {
                                    print(it)
                                }
                        log.error("Error caught :${e} \n")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Record domain

```
package movie

class Record {
    //static searchable = true
    //data will be recieved via http://www.omdbapi.com/
    String artwork
    String title
    Date dateReleased
    String pathToFile
    String userRated
    String lengthOfFilm
    String genre
    String plot
    float rating

    static constraints = {
        artwork nullable: true
        title nullable: false, unique: true
        dateReleased nullable: false
        pathToFile nullable: false
        userRated nullable: true
        lengthOfFilm nullable: true
        genre nullable: true
        plot nullable: true, maxSize: 2000
        rating nullable: true
    }
}
```

And finally IndexJob

```
package movie



class IndexJob {
    static triggers = {
        /*
    cronExpression: "s m h D M W Y"
                     | | | | | | `- Year [optional]
                     | | | | | `- Day of Week, 1-7 or SUN-SAT, ?
                     | | | | `- Month, 1-12 or JAN-DEC
                     | | | `- Day of Month, 1-31, ?
                     | | `- Hour, 0-23
                     | `- Minute, 0-59
                     `- Second, 0-59
     */

        cron name: "indexTrigger", cronExpression: "0  0/1 * * * ? *"
    }
    def indexService

    def execute() {
        indexService.indexFiles()

    }
}
```

Comment: You have posted so much code that is not relevant that it is difficult to say what you are doing wrong.  Which line is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
package movie

import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class IndexService {

    static transactional = false

    def grailsApplication
    private cleanText(String title)
    {
        //split string into array via .,+,[,] etc...
        def splitTitle=(title.toLowerCase()).tokenize('+.[]!£$%^+=~#:; \t \n \r \f / \\ { } @ & - ( )')
        //Get rid of extention
        splitTitle.remove(splitTitle.size()-1)

        //Get rid of Dvdrip and author
        //unwanted phrases
        def unwanted=["dvdrip","eng","www","r5","unique","torentz","3xforum","bugz","ro","maxspeed","xvid","720p","bluray","yify","1080p","hd","x264","RARBG","mp3","mp4","flv","brrip","rip"]
        //Get rid of dates
        //get 2000 to current date to put into the unwanted list
        for(i in 2000..3000){unwanted.add(i.toString())}
        //def empty string to put all our cleaned up text into
        def cleanedText = ""
        //cleaning up word mess...
        splitTitle.each {word->
            if(!unwanted.contains(word))
            {
                cleanedText=cleanedText+word+" "
            }
        }
        //returning with +'s
        return (cleanedText[0..-2]).replaceAll("\\s","+")
    }

    def getInfo(String title)
    {
        //returned nice with +
        def cleanTitle=cleanText(title)
        //define my reader
        def scan = new JsonSlurper()
        def scanner =scan.parseText(("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&plot=full&t="+cleanTitle).toURL().text)
        if(scanner.Response=="True")
        {
            /*
            organisied like this:
            String artwork
            String title
            Date dateReleased
            String userRated
            String lengthOfFilm
            String genre
            String plot
            float rating
 */         //returns our info we have scraped
            def imdb = scanner.imdbRating
            if (imdb.equalsIgnoreCase("n/a")) {
                imdb = "0"
            }

            return [
                    true,
                    scanner.Poster,
                    scanner.Title,
                    new Date(scanner.Released),
                    scanner.Rated,
                    scanner.Runtime,
                    scanner.Genre,
                    scanner.Plot,
                    imdb.toFloat()/10
            ]
        }
        else
        {
            return [null,cleanTitle]
        }


    }
    def indexFiles()
    {
        //returns fileLocation
        def fileLocation=grailsApplication.config.grails.movie.location
        //Setup as file object
        def dir = new File(fileLocation)
        //recurse all files
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
            //only create a record if no file test if record exists
            if(Record.findByPathToFile(file.getCanonicalPath())==null) {
                //get record propreties set
                def record = new Record()
                record.pathToFile = file.getCanonicalPath()
                //call to get data of a film returns as a list
                def info = getInfo(file.getName())
                //check if everthing is alright
                if (info[0] == null) {
                    try {
                        //set fallback propeties
                        record.artwork = null
                        record.title = info[1].replaceAll("\\+"," ")
                        record.genre = null
                        record.dateReleased = new Date(file.lastModified())
                        record.lengthOfFilm = null
                        record.plot = null
                        record.rating = 0
                        record.userRated = null
                        record.save(failOnError: true)
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        //catch any errors
                        //log.error("Error caught :${e} \n")
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //set good propeties
                        record.artwork = info[1]
                        record.title = info[2]
                        record.genre = info[6]
                        record.dateReleased = info[3]
                        record.lengthOfFilm = info[5]
                        record.plot = info[7]
                        record.rating = info[8]
                        record.userRated = info[4]
                        record.save(failOnError: true)
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        catch any errors
                        log.error("Error caught :${e} \n")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It took me an hour to work that out!

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to explain I saw you got NumberFormatException error so i just thought it must of been coming from your float which you imported so all i did is catch it and put it to 0.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this stackoverflow system!